# How to make multiple open source web apps use the same database

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to set up an online store and a point of sale application for a food coop. 
My preference is php/mysql, but I can't find any projects which accomplish both these requirements. I was wondering if it would be possible to use separate store and pos apps and get them using the same product database.

The questions I have about this are:

- is it a bad idea?
- Should one of the apps be modified to use the same tables as the other or should there be a database replication process which maps the fields together (is this a common thing?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is it a bad idea?

The greatest danger might be that if someone successfully attacks your online store, then the pos systems might get affected as well. E.g. from a DOS attack. That wouldn't keep me from taking this route, though.

> Should one of the apps be modified to use the same tables as the other or should there be a database replication process which maps the fields together (is this a common thing?)

If you can get at least one of the two systems to use the products data in read only mode, then I'd set up a number of views to translate between the different schemata without physically duplicating any data.